# XSLT group list of children by attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML structure like the following:

```
<parent>
  <child id="1">Text1</child>
  <child id="1">Text2</child>
  <child id="2">Text3</child>
  <child id="1">Text4</child>
  <child id="1">Text5</child>
</parent>
```

And I want to transform the elements, so that I have s.th. like

```
<parent>
  <childrenGroup1>
    <child>Text1</child>
    <child>Text2</child>
  </childrenGroup1>
  <childrenGroup2>
    <child>Text3</child>
  </childrenGroup1>
  <childrenGroup1>
    <child>Text4</child>
    <child>Text5</child>
  </childrenGroup11>
</parent>
```

What is a good way to do this?

I prefer template matching over the for-each loop. But if this can only be solved with a loop, its also no problem.

Comment: A "good way" would be XSLT 2.0 and `<xsl:for-each-group select="child" group-adjacent="@id">...</xsl:for-each-group>`. Can you use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or AltovaXML or XmlPrime?

Comment: Ahrghh, 'group-adjacent' is the magic key. Yes, I can use saxon 9.5. Plz can you write this as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With XSLT 2.0 it is straight-forward:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="parent">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="child" group-adjacent="@id">
      <xsl:element name="childrenGroup{current-grouping-key()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="child/@id"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```